# is there a method to `eat` the signal in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

i use a for loop to send request to `http://www.example.com`:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        request.setUrl("http://www.example.com");

        manager.get(request);
    }
```

and i want to handle the reply parallel, so i run 10 threads, each threads has a slot function to add the reply to a `Qvector<QNetworkReply*>`. i connect this 10 slot function to the signal `finished(QNetworkReply*)` of `manager`. in this case, when the `finished(QNetworkReply*)` emitted, this 10 slot function will called to add this reply to the vector 10 times. i want to if a thread has handle the function, and the rest of the 9 threads drop  this signal to wait another signal emitted. is there a method to eat the `finished(QNetworkReply*)` in the first slot?

Comment: Currently, it is somewhat unclear and odd what you are asking. Could you please provide a bit more code that represents what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

I think what you are looking for is a Thread Pool to handle requests.  A bunch of workers waiting to do the same thing, and once there is a request to handle it.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#details

> The `QThreadPool` class manages a collection of `QThread`s.
>
> `QThreadPool`
>   manages and recyles individual `QThread` objects to help reduce thread
>   creation costs in programs that use threads. Each Qt application has
>   one global `QThreadPool` object, which can be accessed by calling
>   `globalInstance()`.
>
> To use one of the `QThreadPool` threads, subclass `QRunnable` and
>   implement the `run()` virtual function. Then create an object of that
>   class and pass it to `QThreadPool::start()`.

https://www.google.com/search?q=qthreadpool+network

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpServer_QThreadPool_Multithreaded_Client_Server.php

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you are saying, you've got 10 slots (one in each of 10 threasds) connected to one signal. And you'd like only one of them to run on each emit.

That's NOT how Qt signals work. Qt signals fire each and every slot connected to the signal each and every time the signal is emitted. You want more of a message queue, where may workers can wait on the queue.

You might want to look at the QWaitCondition [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-waitconditions.html) - wait conditions are one way you could implement having the workers wait for something to do.